# 1452; Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, magento

How do I solve this?
Am importing a csv file through Store Manager Magento but I received this error:

> 1452; Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
>   (`ccmcnige_f3june`.`customer_entity`, 
> CONSTRAINT >FK_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID`FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`)<br> >REFERENCES`core_store`(`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CAS)
>   UPDATE customer_entity SET store_id='1' WHERE entity_id = 3;

I don't know a thing about sql. I have access to phpmyadmin by the way.

Thank you.

Comment: It actually has to do with mysql, it is a mysql question and i have seen many sql questions here.

Comment: If it is a programming-related question regarding MySQL then it is OK. If it is a debug a Magento import, that happens to throw up SQL as part of the error, then it is not. Because you say you don't know a thing about SQL it doesn't sound like you are programming it.